# Is FarmWarDeployer compatible with Tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat, farmwardeployer

Can I use FarmWarDeployer with TomCat 7? Or will I have to use Tomcat 5.5? Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

The TomCat 7.0 documentation exposes the FarmWarDeployer classes:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/ha/deploy/FarmWarDeployer.html

So it would be safe to assume that yes, it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I know that what the farmwardeployer but dont know how to use the functionality provided by that. Means I know the configuration within <Cluster> element but How to test by deploying application in one place(which place).